# Count divs with jquery and output

Tags: jquery, count

I want to automatically count the number of divs with the class ".item". After that, I want jQuery to output the number in a another div within .item, with the class ".itemnumber". So I want the first div to output "1", the second div to output "2", and so on. I know how to count, but I don't know how to output the number for earch div..

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Please accept answers to your questions!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you?

There might be a more optimized solution, but try this:

```
var count = $('div.item').length; //Get all items with class "div", which returns an array... so you just use the "length" to get the total count.

$('div.item').each(function(k,v){ //.each takes a first argument which is a function, and this function takes 2 arguments "k"ey and "v"alue.
    //v in this case is the div, so:
    $('.itemnumber',v).html('Div #' + String(k+1));
});
```

Let me know if there's any doubt.

Cheers!

Comment: That totally did the trick! Awesome, thank you. Do you also know how to put a "0" in front of the first 9 items. So that I get 01, 02 ... 08, 09, 10, 11

Comment: Glad it worked.

As for padding your number, the quick solution would be to implement this function:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/pad-number-two-digits-javascript/

However, I do recommend to use the PHPJS.org's function for str_pad like this:

http://phpjs.org/functions/str_pad:525

This will allow you to use the full power of str_pad, rather than just for 2 digits.

Cheers!

Comment: By the way, keep in mind that the var "count" is not being used at all, I just placed it there in case you wanted to know the total amount of divs with class "item" beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="itemnumber"></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
   <div class="itemnumber"></div>
</div>
```

If your HTML is like that (at a guess), then there's no reason to count the elements, you'd simple do this:

```
$.each(".item", function(i, val) {
   $(this).find(".itemnumber").text(i)
});
```